# Odd plotting/math issue (could be a precision problem)

Tags: plotting, special-functions, precision-and-accuracy, machine-precision

I've got a pretty odd error on a project I'm working on and was hoping to enlist some advice to fix it. The goal of this notebook is to show that I can eliminate the non-normalizable (blowing up part) of the Whittaker W function for small arguments by multiplying by a constant.

I first start by defining the W function in a more convenient way:

```
f[r_, k_, w_, v_] := WhittakerW[-I*(k^2/(4*w)), v, -I*r^2*w]
```

Expanding f (`Series[f[r, k, w, v], {r, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> {r>0, w>0, v>0, k>0}]`) I see that the constant I need to multiply by is $c = \frac{\Gamma[1/2 + \nu + i(k^2/(4*\omega))]}{(-i)^{1/2 - \nu}}$. This is the imaginary term on all of the non-normalizable parts of $W$ (you can see this if you include higher order terms in the series expansion). So multiplying by this should, in principle, wipe out the imaginary part of the non-normalizable piece, and leave me with a normalizable imaginary part. Unfortunately, it isn't working out this way in *Mathematica*:

```
const[k_,w_,v_] = Gamma[1/2 + v + I*(k^2/(4*w))]/(-I)^(1/2 - v)
LogLogPlot[Abs[Im[const[10, .01, 3.1]*f[r, 10, .01, 3.1]]], {r, 0.001, .01}]
```

The above plot shows a line with negative slope, going to infinity, rather than zero. When I define a function for the Taylor series, however:

```
bdry2[r_] = 
 Normal[FullSimplify[
   Series[const[10, .01, 3.1]*f[r, 10, .01, 3.1], {r, 0, 5}, 
    Assumptions -> r > 0]]]
```

The plot: `LogLogPlot[{Abs[Im[bdry2[r]]]}, {r, 0.000001, .001}]` is normalizable. So this is quite confusing for me, and I think there is some sort of rounding error going on -- but I'm not quite sure where my error lies. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe it is a precision issue, try this to force high precision calculation: `N[const[10, 1/100, 31/10]*f[2/1000, 10, 1/100, 31/10], 100]` you will see the result is purely real .

Comment: Ok - interesting. It seems the imaginary part is 10^(-84) here -- whereas without including as much precision, it was probably non-negligible. Any idea how I can implement this level of precision into my plotting?

Comment: I suspect this requires more of a mathematics study of the function rather than relying on numerical evaluation even at high precision.

Comment: I think I have good reason to believe what I'm doing is possible numerically -- there are only a couple terms in the taylor series that are non-normalizable (for small v, but still this should hold for any v) -- and they all have some factor $c*r^{-\gamma}$, where $c$ is complex -- so dividing by c should make the coefficient of that term real. Not quite sure I understand the difficulty Mathematica's having with it

Comment: Schwinger, you should be able to implement increased precision in your plot using arbitrary precision arguments as mentioned by @george2079, by specifying the plotting range in the same way (i.e. `{r, 1/1000, 1/100}`), and finally by using the `WorkingPrecision` option to the plotting function. For instance, you could use `WorkingPrecision -> 100`.

Comment: Is somthing like this what you want, `LogLogPlot[Abs[Im[const[10, 1/100, 31/10]*f13[r, 10, 1/100, 31/10]]], {r, 0.001, .01}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]`?